# Definir o desaparecer texto al recibir undefined javaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined, innerhtml

estoy haciendo un sistema de usuario el cual obtiene datos generados por el mismo y los descarga de un array, los datos son cargados por la posición del array y mostrados mediante el dom, el campo ya esta predefinido pero obvio al no tener nada dentro del array en la posición ya definida al rellenarlo tira undefined, por ejemplo:

Nombre: ${usuario[0]}

Mail: ${usuario[1]}

Residencia: ${usuario[3]}

Dirección: ${usuario[4]}

Código Postal: ${usuario[5]}

Celular: ${usuario[6]}

Al tener 4 elementos dentro del array en en código postal y celular tira undefined
Código Postal: undefined
Celular: undefined
y tengo el problema que pensé solucionar de dos posibles formas pero no se como realizarlas:

1. definir que si es undefined tire un mensaje predefinido como por ejemplo 'Sin datos' o
2. que las líneas que no tengan datos no se muestren.
   Gracias!